# Framework/lib/pattern to secure rest endpoint

Tags: java, rest, security, http, web

Generally all rest based framework provide authenticate.
But are there any framework/lib/pattern that helps to secure rest endpoint with following capability

**`Only a authenticated user with following roles can access a end point with only particular params.`**

Basically i am trying to prevent two user(with same roles) to view each other data by passing each other id in request urls

Comment: [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) springs to mind. Pun intended.

Comment: please read comment on the first answer, and last line in question description

Comment: Spring security is **much** more flexible than Shiro and you can certainly do what you want. Through a number of different paths actually. It will require becoming rather familiar with the documentation as this isn't standard.

Comment: @BoristheSpider can you point to some resource each shows how to acheive it

Comment: You can extend [SPEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) with custom [expression handler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/) to evaluate basically any restriction. You can combine this with method security to restrict access to individual methods with something like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin') && hasCorrectId()")`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you should look at [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/authorization-features.html) it offers really good support role base/permission based authorization.

An example of how you can annotate an endpoint would be:

`@RequiresRoles(value = "admin")`

I'd recommend you to check the [Instance-Level Access Control](http://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html) of this document.

Comment: @RequiresRoles(value = "admin") will allow only admins to access the end point, which is fine but two different admin of two different company can still access each other data by passing each other ID, in request url For eg: /getcriticaldata/:ID

Comment: Yeah totally, that was meant to be just an example, `permission-based` authorization seems to be what you're looking for where an admin might have permission to access a resource but not another. Will point you to an example of permission base checks in a minute.

Comment: Added the link in the response, hope it helps!

Comment: Also if you are looking on how to try it, here is the tutorial link: http://shiro.apache.org/webapp-tutorial.html#step7

Comment: Awesome looks like going in right direction...but i wonder how it is going to handle simple cases like : Two admin A with id A and admin B with id B. each admin has a list of user A has [c,d,e] and B has [f,g,h]..Now how shiro is going to save us ? do i have to say [A:access:c], [A:access:d], [A:access:e], [B:access:f], [B:access:g],[B:access:h]...basically what if my permission logic is code ?

Comment: yep you can think like that

Comment: That would be the idea, you define the permissions for each one, so when user C, is authenticated you'd be assigning the permissions based on the role, let's say [criticaldata:read:anId], then the user tries to access the resource you'd be checking against the permissions granted for the user.

Comment: You'd be using something like  SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted(permissionToCheck); this is Shiro terminology but the subject is the authenticated user.

Comment: i understand that but where will i be inserting my custom code of permission check

Comment: In you endpoints code, or where you want some resource to be authorized before executing something, then you can construct your permission based on runtime data, lets say String permissionToCheck = "criticaldata"+id+"read", then you check if the subject is permitted to it.